# Modifying the Account settings Fields/ Registration form in Drupal 7

Tags: theming

I would like to add some markup so to explain a question section before going into the questions... How can I do this?

One of the questions is a Dropdown list, and one of the options is "Other, please specify). How would I go about adding the Other field so that it is a part of the same question? I was thinking a fieldset, but there doesn't seem to be that option?

I would like to add a label that is 200 characters long (including spaces), but at the moment it is being cut off.

Comment: are you talking about grouping fields together?

Answer (score 0):

Though I have never done this but I am pretty sure you can do it by [form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). You will have to add field as per your requirement and add description to the field by this hook.

Description can be based on selected value of the option list also. A simple example for this hook for user register is here --

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){ //Replace your module name by MYMODULE.
  if($form['#id'] == 'user-register-form'){
    $form['account']['mail']['#description'] = t(''); //Removing description from email field.
    $form['account']['pass']['#description'] = t(''); //Removing description from password field.
  }
}
```

Play around & I hope you will find solution.

Comment: Thank you @RajeevK
Do I need to create a custom module to put the hook in?

Comment: @user19417 - You will have to make small module for applying form_alter